# Client Side Validation, disabled_validators = [:uniqueness], returns 500 http status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, http, client

In my rails4 project I am using the client side validation [gem](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/tree/4-0-beta) (branch 4-0-beta).

For security reasons I have disabled the uniqueness validation in the config/initializers/client_side_validations.rb file.

> ClientSideValidations::Config.disabled_validators = [:uniqueness]

This works fine and when I test in the browser whether a user email exists I get a 500 status no matter if the user exists or not.

> http://localhost:3000/validators/uniqueness?case_sensitive=false&id=01&user[email]=tester@mail.com&_=1379052030490

(If uniqueness is not disabled I get a 200 or 404 status response dependent on whether the user is unique or not.)

**HTTP Status Code**

However I am not sure if I understand correctly the status code defined in middleware.rb:

> client_side_validations / lib / client_side_validations / middleware.rb

```
  def call(env)
    if matches = /^\/validators\/(\w+)$/.match(env['PATH_INFO'])
      if ClientSideValidations::Config.disabled_validators.include?(matches[1].to_sym)
        [500, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Content-Length' => '0'}, ['']]
      else
        "::ClientSideValidations::Middleware::#{matches[1].camelize}".constantize.new(env).response
      end
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

My understanding is that status code 500 should be used for server errors ("A generic error message, given when no more specific message is suitable"). However in this case the uniqueness validation is disabled on purpose and I was therefore thinking whether a 403 "Forbidden" or 405 "Method not allowed" would be more appropriate?

The reason why I am not too happy about the 500 status is that Chrome will automatically display a server error message, and since the client_side_validation gem is not raising an exception, which I can catch within rails, I am stuck with Chrome's default server error message for 500 status code.

Any advice on the appropriate status code in this situation or alternative solutions would be cool.